# beginners architectural topic on c++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, architecture, encapsulation

Coming from pure "C" I'm a c++ novice and more or less new to OO-Development at all, therefore I apologize in advance for my "naive" view of the topic below. In the following I tried to describe my problem in an abstract style (my real classes are different). The code parts could be un-compilable, and should be seen as a "thought" only.

I have several Classes, inheriting from a base class:

```
    class Base
    {

    };


    class Derived1 : Base
    {

    };

    class Derived2 : Base
    {

    };

    class Derived3 : Base
    {

    };
```

Moreover, a vector contains pointers to instances of the derived classes:

```
    std::vector<Base *> collection;
```

Now I want to provide this class scheme to be usable for other users.
The problem: When the user iterates over the collection, how does he/she know about the concrete class type? Providing virtual member functions to the derived classes is not a nice option, because I don't know in advance , what the user wants to do.

Should he/she use dynamic_cast(...) to obtain the concrete class? Not nice...

After hours of thinking I ended up with the following "solution", but I'm not sure if that is real nice or total bullshit:

Defining an interface for a user object, operating on the mentioned classes:

```
    class Derived1;
    class Derived2;
    class Derived3;

    class AbstractUserOperation
    {
        virtual void call(Derived1 * cl) = 0;
        virtual void call(Derived2 * cl) = 0;
        virtual void call(Derived3 * cl) = 0;
    };
```

The user defines a concrete class, based on that interface, to realize his/her desired operation for each possible type of my derived classes:

```
    class ConcreteUserOperation : AbstractUserOperation
    {
        virtual void call(Derived1 * cl)
        {
            ...
        }

        virtual void call(Derived2 * cl)
        {
            ...
        }

        virtual void call(Derived3 * cl)
        {
            ...
        }

    };
```

My own classes as before, extended by "evaluate":

```
    class Base
    {
        virtual void evaluate(AbstractUserOperation* o) = 0;

    };


    class Derived1 : public Base
    {
        void evaluate(AbstractUserOperation *o)
        {
            o->call(this);
        }

    };

    class Derived2 : public Base
    {
        void evaluate(AbstractUserOperation *o)
        {
            o->call(this);
        }

    };

    class Derived3 : public Base
    {
        void evaluate(AbstractUserOperation *o)
        {
            o->call(this);
        }
    };
```

Usage as follows:

```
    std::vector<Base *> collection;

    ConcreteUserOperation o; // a user defined class, doing whatever with x

    x = collection[i];

    x->evaluate(&o); // call user defined operation o on x
```

Of course, this is somehow "complicated", but, at least, everything is up to the user defining the concrete operation class, which is completely separated from my class scheme.

Is that approach acceptable from an architectural point of view ???
Hopefully that was not too boring for all the experts here ;-)

Many many thanks,
Michael

Comment: Usually when you use subtype polymorphism you don’t care about the dynamic type of an object. You might want to use `boost::variant` instead of inheritance. Also, remember that more often than not, inheritance is not the best way to do it in C++, which provides other powerful ways to do polymorphism such as templates and overloading (with and without ADL).

Comment: You might also want public inheritance.

Comment: _'Defining an interface for a user object, operating on the mentioned classes:'_ Defining an interface is the first natural approach, and perfectly fine.

Comment: You've just discovered the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: boost::variant is exactly what I need. With that I could forget all my previous considerations ;-)

Comment: What you describe is the visitor pattern. It is good way to prepare for expected addition of new operations to a fixed data structure because it localizes the changes needed to add a new operation without modifying the data structure (open-closed principle). However, it fails when the data structure inheritance tree changes, e.g. a new Derived4 type is introduced. Then, you will have to modify all visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert for this visitor concept, but I use similar code and i always think of it as callbacks. I think, you don't even need to define a interface for ConcreteUserOperation if you allow calls to Derived's evaluate with something like std::function as callback argument. Then you should even be able to plug in lambdas as visitors. Samplecode:

```
  #include <functional>

  struct Base {};

  struct Derived : public Base
  {
     void evaluate(std::function<void(const Derived&)> callback) const
     {
        callback(*this);
     }

     int foo = 42;
  };

  int main()
  {
     Derived d;
     d.evaluate([](const Derived& d){std::cout << d.foo << std::endl;});
  }
```

Life example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/223af4a43077a760